# Join multiple SPF in one string

Tags: domain, spf, txt-record

I've read other thread about it but I've 2 different string with some parameters in only one (MX) so i ask some help to join in one string only in the correct way.

1) `"v=spf1 include:spf.sendinblue.com mx ~all"`

2) `"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all"`

Is correct a result string like:

```
"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:spf.sendinblue.com mx -all"
```

the first record have a mx parameter that the second ercord not have, so I've some doubt about that

thank you for any help or explanation.

Hart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include `mx` if the mail server which handles your incoming mail for your domain is also allowed to send outgoing mail for your domain. For most setups this is true. It is irrelevant whether it appears in someone else's example. What is relevant is your own needs.

Comment: In many setups it is indeed true, especially for smaller scale mail services. However with `include:spf.protection.outlook.com` being one of the entries, I would think this is likely not one of those setups (it suggests that `MX` is likely the `outlook.com` servers).

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist That is true. If your mail is being sent from O365 then you don't need `mx`.

Comment: usually MX in SPF is needed if you use your own mail server (on premise or VPS). For Cloud based emails providers (Google, Microsoft, Zoho, NameCheap private mail, etc) you just need to add "include" statement, provided by ESP.

Comment: the mx parameter was only needed by sendinblue servers (alternative to  mailchimp). My question was if my final joined configuration was correct or not because if i put mx in the joined strig it works for both outlook and sendinblue?. Thanks

Comment: @Hart I don't know if it's correct or not, only you know that. Please read the answer above.

Comment: Sendinblue does not require use your MX servers for sending mails. You just need to add include:sendinblue.com to existing SPF. https://mxtoolbox.com/c/outboundemailsources?public=SendinBlue

Comment: @Zonder thank you for your comment. the parameters was given during the DNS authentication on sendinblue site. the mx parameter was on the string to add to the dns. anyway i will try to remove mx parameter or in case of problerms i will use another domain authentication :)

Comment: @Hart , I would recommend you to signup for free plan of one or DMARC analyzing tool, e.g. https://easydmarc.com/tools. You will be able to validate syntax of SPF and also setup DMARC to monitor your outgoing emails DMARC compliance status

Comment: @zonder, thank yuo so much for the tool. I've discovered that the DMARC string suggested by sendinblue is not valid: https://help.sendinblue.com/hc/en-us/articles/208848209-How-to-customize-your-DKIM-signature after the email they add !10m that is something wrong. I'm quite confused :)